# Parsing XML with filter

Tags: java, xml

i parse XML document in java with:

```
doc = DocumentBuilderFactory
           .newInstance()
           .newDocumentBuilder()
           .parse(new URL(url).openStream());
```

work, but is possible to parse with some filter? for example my XML file have one attribute priority, is possible to parse with filter for example priority>8 ?

So in the doc have only element with priority > 8.

Example xml:

```
<url>
<loc>http</loc>
<lastmod>2015-02-26</lastmod>
<title>Hello</titolo>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Once you've built the xml document, you can fire an xpath to get just the nodes you're interested in. If you post your xml format, perhaps we can help you with that.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal but with xpath i must parse and after use xpath right?

Comment: Yes, it would require a full DOM tree in memory against which your xpath expression would then be evaluated.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal sorry for my bad english, is not what i want, because i want the DOM tree only element with priority > 8 (for example)

Comment: The result of the xpath query would be a DOM tree with only the elements with priority > 8. The xpath would however be applied on the full tree to extract only the nodes that match your priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following sample input file named urls.xml

```
<root>
    <url>
        <loc>http</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-02-26</lastmod>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-02-26</lastmod>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <priority>7.0</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-02-26</lastmod>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <priority>10.0</priority>
    </url>
</root>
```

You first create the full `Document` tree as usual

```
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory
           .newInstance()
           .newDocumentBuilder()
           .parse(new File("urls.xml"));
```

Then run the `XPath` query that selects all the `Node`s above a certain `priority`

```
XPathExpression expr = XPathFactory.newInstance()
                      .newXPath().compile("//url[priority > 5]");
NodeList urls = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

If you want to serialize the results to another xml file, create a new `Document` first.

```
Document result = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        .newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
Node root = result.createElement("results");
result.appendChild(root);
```

Then append the filtered url `Node`s as

```
for (int i = 0; i < urls.getLength(); i++) {
    Node copy = result.importNode(urls.item(i), true);
    root.appendChild(result.createTextNode("\n\t"));
    root.appendChild(copy);
}
root.appendChild(result.createTextNode("\n"));
```

Now, all you need to do is to serialize the new `Document` to a `String` and write that out to a file. Here's I'm just printing it out on to the console.

```
System.out.println(
        ((DOMImplementationLS) result.getImplementation())
        .createLSSerializer().writeToString(result));
```

***Output:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<results>
    <url>
        <loc>http</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-02-26</lastmod>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <priority>7.0</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-02-26</lastmod>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <priority>10.0</priority>
    </url>
</results>
```

Comment: and is possible to use lastmod attribute in the expression? for example only node have lastmod > 2015-all-all (only 2015)

Comment: Yeah, sure. Just use `//url[priority > 8 and starts-with(lastmod, '2015-')]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use XPath to find the elements you require:

```
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile([your xpath here]);
```

Then...

```
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc);
```

... to get the nodes you require. You can use...

```
for(Node node in nl) {
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    }
}
```

... to pull out only the genuine elements.

Of course, you'll need to also build up a basic XPath expression to find the nodes you require.

Comment: but with xpath i must parse and after use xpath right?

Comment: No, you parse the document first into "doc" (as per your example) and then use XPath to filter the results.

Comment: so isn't possible to parse with filter?

Comment: and for my example what i set into xpath.compile() ?

Comment: @AntonioBalduzzi Use `//url[priority > 8]` as the xpath expression.